# What is this small black bug found in Turkey?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

What species is this? It was found in Turkey. It was dead, I did not kill it.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a scarab beetle (Coleoptera, Scarabaeidae). Species is difficult to tell without better pictures, but perhaps *Scarabaeus typhon*?

**Edit**: OP has IDed in comment as *Scarabaeus jalof*

Comment: @Oğuzİsmayiluysal If you think this answer is correct, we encourage you to accept it.

Comment: Definitely looks like a member of *Scarabaeus* but why *S. typhon*?

Comment: @augurar I forgot to edit my comment it is not typhon. It is a S. jalof. https://c4.staticflickr.com/4/3510/3847992837_b3aa34f400_b.jpg